# Cities and colors java

Tags: java, eclipse, recursion, colors

the problem consists in that you have to solve a problem where exists n-cities and n-colors , every city have a color but the cities adjacent can't have the same color.
The teacher send this homework for investigate how to solve it , we are working on java - eclipse and we are so confused . Can you help us being really explicit , thanks so much.   the last topic was recursion.
P.D: some people say that it solve by graphs but we are not sure and we dont understand really good .

Comment: If there are n cities and n colours can't you just paint every city a different colour?

Comment: No because , it is possible that exists cities not-adyacent with the same color

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would make 2 loops for, one inside the other, like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < n_cities; i++)
{
  for (j = 0; j < n_colours; j++)
  {
  }
}
```

In this way, you will be able to walk all the possible combinations. In the second loop, you will have to make the comparison if the cities around citie i have the same colour, if not, try with the next colour, and this for all the n-iterations.

How to know if the cities adjacent are with the same colour? Well, you can create a n-vector in which you will save all the colours of all the cities. The position of the vector could be the i-citie and the value saved in the position could be the colour of this citie.

I expect it will be useful for you :)

Answer (score 0):

There are probably many solutions, but the first one that came to mind is having an ArrayList containing CityColor instances. My CityColor class holds the city name and color. When adding to the ArrayList, you would check to make sure the adjacent elements of the ArrayList do not have the same color. If it does have the same color, use recursion to select another color until you get an acceptable color.

Your ArrayList would have objects such as:

```
public class CityColor {

private String city;
private String color;

public CityColor(String city, String color) {
    this.city = city;
    this.color = color;
}

// set/get methods for the variables

}
```

If you have an array of colors, you can use Math.Random to select a random color. If the color matches an adjacent color, use recursion to select another.